# Numbered list not starting at 1

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I recently wanted to quote a part of a technical document, such as this:

> #### 6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers
>
> 8. As a special case, a type name (which is not a declaration of an identifier) is considered to have a scope that begins just after the place within the type name where the omitted identifier would appear were it not omitted.

This works fine, except that the quoted paragraph is number **8**, not number 1.

Is there any way to make the list start at a particular number (eg. `<ol start=8>`)?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137077/cant-start-a-numbered-list-on-a-number-other-than-1

Comment: Now if someone would implement that... Maybe only for posts edited after that date, to minimize breakage... You see that [@balpha's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137085/257849) is already 2 years old, and easily overlooked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature has now been implemented. Old posts will not be re-rendered until they are edited. See [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) for more details.