# Preview differs from the real

Tags: discussion, editor

A few minutes ago I decided to edit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20867286/1841194) to reformat it into a tidy list instead of (a)... (b)... .

When I clicked on `edit` button it showed its raw source. As you can see there, that sentence has begun with *"13. Beneﬁts"* (in either raw format and preview), but in real case it has begun with *"1. Beneﬁts"*.

What's this? A bug or a feature I'm not aware of?

---

**Real:**

[image]

**Preview:**

[image]

Comment: Some screenshots to clarify maybe? I've noticed, that e.g. horizontal bars aren't rendered correctly in preview recently. Also note that numbered lists are calculating the starting number independently of the actual number you give them in the markup.

Comment: Highly related, potentially dupe: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262322/numbered-list-not-starting-at-1 See also on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239121/266735 (Bascially, just edit that answer and it should fix the numbering.)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Until recently, users weren't allowed to start an ordered list at some arbitrary number - the system would always force the number to start at 1. That change a little bit ago, and now users *are* allowed to start an ordered list at any number they'd like.

What you're seeing is an artifact of that change. The system permanently caches the rendered post until it is updated. In this case, it has a cache of raw text rendered under the old system where the list was forced to start at 1. When trying to edit it *now* without that restriction, the list is starting at 13 under the new rules of how the Markdown gets rendered, and the final output will change to 13 if you save an edit over it.

Comment: any natural number but zero...

Comment: @Deduplicator  Odd... zeroth is a perfectly valid ordinal.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroth_law_of_thermodynamics , for example.

Comment: @J...: [Markup enumeration bug: Preview starts at 1, final output starts correctly at 0](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271640) and [Should the system override my numbering?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284387) The resolution was unfortunate and surprising...